# Flutter remove where command

Tags: flutter, dart

i have created list builder of tasks with CheckBox. I've created button on clicked to delete only tasks when checkbox is true. This is code where i want to remove only tasks with selected checkboxes

```
              widget.selectedList.productsAndStatus.removeWhere(() => true);
              await ProductsList.editSavedListName(widget.selectedList, widget.selectedListIndex);
              setState(() {});
```

Can you help me what to write to removeWhere(() => true) please?
Here is checkbox code

```
Widget productCell(int index, Map productCell){
bool productStatus = productCell["productStatus"];
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    productStatus = !productStatus;
    setState(() {
      setState(() {
        editProductStatus(productStatus, index);
      });
    });
  },
```

this is selectedList class

```
class SavedProducts extends StatefulWidget {
ProductsList selectedList;
int selectedListIndex;
SavedProducts({this.selectedList, this.selectedListIndex});

@override
_SavedProductsState createState() => _SavedProductsState();
}
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more code ? Where does `widget.selectedList` come from ? Is is your parent list ? How do you know that an item is selected in the parent list ?

Comment: I updated a code, selected list in class @BabC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BabC asked good questions, have you tried something like:
widget.selectedList.productsAndStatus.removeWhere((item) => item['productStatus'] == true);
See the docs for [removeWhere](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/removeWhere.html)